# Append text field value to URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of URLs:

```
localhost/action/add/234
localhost/action/add/244
localhost/action/add/334
localhost/action/add/254
```

In front of these values there is a text box, and when a value is typed into the box I want to append it to the end of the URL.

```
localhost/action/add/234/test text1
localhost/action/add/244/test text2
localhost/action/add/334/test text3
localhost/action/add/254/test text4
```

Can someone explain me how can I do it? I found out that its possible to do it using `.val()` but I'm unsure how to use it.

Comment: Where do you have this "list of urls?"

Comment: @AshwinMukhija im goin through http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val on how to do it. im new to jquery learning stuff

Comment: @ExplosionPills these urls are retrieved from the database based on a id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to update immediately:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var a = $('#url').text();
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(){
      var b = $('#textbox').val();
      $('#url').text(a + '/test ' + b);
      $('#url').attr('href', a + '/test ' + b);
    });
  });
</script>

<input id='textbox' type='text'></input>
<a href="localhost/action/add/234" id='url'>localhost/action/add/234</a>
```

The key things here are

- use the `.keyup()` event to run the function whenever a keyboard key is released
- modify the `.text()` of the url element on keyup
- modify the `'href'` attribute of the url element so that the link matches the text

Normally `.val()` is used to set/get the value of input elements, like the text box ^, or a dropdown

Comment: Update: http://jsfiddle.net/qYC6F/1/ <--I edited the answer and the fiddle to include an href for the url which might have been what you were originally having trouble with.  I don't think you can use .val() for an <a href> element

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to append the text that you typed in the textfield to the href (URL).
I think we can make it more simple.

Here is the working solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').on('click', function(e) {
 var search_url = e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href; //or else you can grab the URL anywhere from your DOM;
e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = search_url + $('#search_term').val();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_term" placeholder="Search..StackOverflow" />
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" id="search">Search </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
   var currVal = $('.url').text();
   $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function() {
     $('.url').text(currVal.trim()+$(this).val().trim());    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="url">
   localhost/action/add/234
</span>
   <input type="text" id="search_term" placeholder="blabla" />
```